# fullpage.js setAllowScrolling

Tags: fullpage.js

I have tried to disable the scrolling down on section 4 into section 5.
Does not seem to respond to this:

```
        if(anchorLink == 'support-contact' && slideIndex == 0) {
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down'); 
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false, 'down');
        }
```

support-contact is set here (section 5 not set as it is hidden section):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
initialize(false);
function initialize(hasScrollBar){
$('#fullPage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['home', 'livingwell', 'happybuy', 'support-contact'],
    loopHorizontal: false,
    controlArrows: true,
    menu: '#menu',
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide an isolated reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen. It is working as expected as can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/1kyuL4em/42/

But notice the `afterSlideLoad` or `onSlideLeave` callbacks won't get fired when landing in the section as a result of a vertical movement. 
Only horizontal movements will fire them.

So you probably want to also make use of the `afterLoad` or `onLeave` callbacks and calculate the index of the current slide within the horizontal slider by using something like the following:

```
$('.fp-section.active).find('.fp-slide').index();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your feedback. Yes your isolation shows the trouble i am having. You are also correct with why. So from "support-contact" scrolling vertically to the next section should be blocked. In order to do this i should integrate the the above function. I will have a go my script is not that great. Is there a working example of this?

Comment: Still not getting anywhere with this, is there anymore detail you can part with i have searched github and stackoverflow for similar statements but nothing as of yet will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to re-open, but I have the same issue with a fullpage.js based website.
I have 8 sections, each one with only 2 slides.
The first slide is full screen, but the second is a long scrolling page.
I want that when on the 2nd, it is not possible to scroll up or down to the next or previous section, but that we can only use the "previous" arrow to go back to the first slides.
I have tried both functions below, but none is working.

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex){
var thisSlide = $('.fp-section.active').find('.fp-slide').index();
if(thisSlide === 1){
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up, down');
}
},


afterLoad: function(slideIndex){
if(slideIndex === 1){
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up, down');
}
},
```

If I simply use this function :

```
afterLoad: function(){
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up, down');
},
```

It works, but the vertical scrolling is also disabled on the first slides, which is not what I intend to do.

If anyone has an idea, thanks!

Comment: see below i have given what worked for me in the end

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this was the best way to solve the issue but i worked for me in then end. Hope it helps you. If you get stuck shout me.I have hit the wall so many times i have a few work around for things. im a crap programmer but i try. There is better guys out here but silent.

So i target the sections and give each one an instruction so it does not carry the instruction from the previous slide:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
if(index == 3 && anchorLink == 'golden-visa'){
    $('body.fp-viewing-slidefree').find('.fp-section').index();
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'all'); 
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true, 'all');
}   
if(index == 4 && anchorLink == 'ahimsa-investments'){
    $('body.fp-viewing-ahimsa-investments').find('.fp-section').index();
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down'); 
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false, 'down');
}
if(index == 5 && anchorLink == 'investment-information'){
    $('body.fp-viewing-investment-information').find('.fp-section').index();
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'all'); 
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false, 'all');
        }
},
```

I have another similar issue which i posted here but it seems no one gets back to me. A shame... This is certainly an issue maybe a bug but cant get around it and stuck with a product that should work:

[Fullpage.js disable vertical scroll on section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228319/fullpage-js-disable-vertical-scroll-on-section)