# Fullpage.js disable vertical scroll on section

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I require one section to be "hidden". As i have links that "silentMove" to the slides in the section.

I have tried to use the following with no luck data anchor is "investments":

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
if(index == 4 && slideAnchor == 'investments'){
$('body.fp-section.investments').find('.fp-slide').index(4,0);
    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down'); 
    $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false, 'down');
}
},
```

Only solution i could come up with was:

```
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    if(index == 4 && anchorLink == 'investment'){
    $('body.fp-viewing-investment').find('.fp-section').index();
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down'); 
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false, 'down');
    }
  if(index == 3 && anchorLink == 'section3'){
    $('body.fp-viewing-section3').find('.fp-section').index();
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'down'); 
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true, 'down');
    }
```

This is a shorter code, but you can not leave section 5, once you enter with silent move to:

```
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.body.className += " no-scroll";}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4wvwjrta/6/

Comment: You have a typo? You need to close the quote here `$('body.fp-section.investments)`

Comment: what is `.index(4, 0)` doing anyway?

Comment: index 4,0 is section 4 slide 0? i will remove. apart from typo, this is correct way of stopping a section from sliding down into section 5?

Comment: Easier if you just provide a reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen to illustrate your issue. It come on handy for you to read my post about [how to ask questions to get answers](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-not-suck-at-asking-coding-questions/)

Comment: HI, here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4wvwjrta/3/, i had issues with after scrolling up from section 4, i could not scroll back down on any section so added a second command. Is this the best approach.